# Infinite loop How to check if there are same messages in MSMQ

Tags: c#

I'm actually coding a RFID Reader and I puted an infinite loop for reading card.
The card ID is sent to the MSMQ services and I receive this message on another C# app.

Is it possible to check and delete the duplicates messages sent to MSMQ?

Thanks for help

I'm on Visual Studio Code 2017

Comment: Please add code. Find inspiration on how to write good questions here: [ask] and here: [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: One remark, though: I personally would put all messages to the queue and have the receiver sort out dupes. I guess it is much easier there, because you have (easier) access to historcal data.

Comment: I'm sorry about my bad english but i'm trying to do my best

Comment: You are welcome. It's just on SO we appreciate effort. And we prefer helping you help yourself. So if you add code, we can show you how to fix it. Tutorials on how to do things in general are mostly too broad for an answer and not what this site intends to be a source of.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use "GetAllMessages" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue.getallmessages?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get an enumerator over a snapshot of messages in the queue.  Because it is a read-only snapshot, you can't delete messages using this enumerator (and it won't remove messages from the queue just by reading).   This might be the safest way to start as you know that you can only identify duplicates :)  Once you're happy with that code you could switch to "GetMessageEnumerator2" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue.getmessageenumerator2?view=netframework-4.7.2) which allows you to call other methods to remove messages from the queue.

Comment: Hello Paul,
Thank's for the answer.

Comment: No problem @PaulHenry, as a new user - if my (or someone else) answers your problem then don't forget to mark the answer as such: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers